# How to use Oracle Collection of Record type in table?

Tags: oracle, collections, record, user-defined-types

I was trying to explore Oracle Collection and Record type. How do they work ? I wrote below script, but unable to compile them. What is wrong here ?

```
create or replace package pkg is
type ty_rec is record(empno emp.empno%type,ename emp.ename%type,sal emp.sal%type);
end pkg;
/
create or replace package body pkg is 
end pkg;
/
create or replace type ty_varray is varray(5) of pkg.ty_rec;
/
create or replace type ty_table is table of pkg.ty_rec;
/
create table tab1(
id number,
col_arr ty_varray,
col_tab ty_table
) nested table col_tab store as tab1_col_tab;
/
```

Also, anyone could explain the Nested Table vs Varray when we are using them in table column. How do they stores data and which one is faster ?

Note: I'm using scott schema, which has default **emp** table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Records are a PL/SQL construct.  This means they cannot be used in pure SQL statements.  So you need to create the "record" type as a pure SQL object:

```
create or replace type ty_emp_rec as object 
(empno number
  ,ename varchar2(20)
  ,sal number);
/

create or replace type ty_emp_varray is varray(5) of ty_emp_rec;
/
create or replace type ty_emp_table is table of ty_emp_rec;
/
```

I agree it would be highly neat if your code worked, not least because the ability to define attributes using the `%TYPE` syntax would be extremely useful.  But alas that's restricted to the PL/SQL engine too.

This limitation is down to the ability to declare heap table columns with user-defined types, as your last example shows.  Oracle requires its columns to be strongly-typed.  The `%TYPE` syntax would create all sorts of problems here: consider what would happen if `emp.empno` changed from NUMBER to VARCHAR2, or vice versa.

Comment: Awesome..!!! I was trying to use `%TYPE` in object declaration, but I was getting error. Now, I came to know why. Thanks for your reply.